# Plotting inequalities on a number line

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code seems to do the trick. However, I want to draw boxes when I can really visualize the overlap between the two inequalities. How do you draw the upper arrows as given in the image?

```
{\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[latex-] (-1,0) -- (9,0) ;
\draw[-latex] (-1,0) -- (9,0) ;
\foreach \x in  {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\x$};
\draw[*-o] (2.98,0) -- (5.02,0);
\draw[very thick    ] (2.98,0) -- (5.02,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: What I want to achieve]

Comment: What's the `{` at the beginning of the code? Maybe you forgot it? Also, you loaded `pgfplots` twice. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use relative coordinates:

```
\draw [red,  thick, -stealth] (5,0) -- ++(0,0.5) -- ++(-5,0);
```

This is interpreted as start at `(5,0)` and draw line to a point that is at `++(0,0.5)` relative to the current location. Thus, a line is drawn to `(5,0.5)`. Similarly, the `++(-5,0)` means to draw the line to `(5,0.5)+(-5,0)=(0,0.5)`.

[image]

As per @Tom Bombadil's comment, you can also use the `|-` syntax.  So

```
\draw [red,  thick, -stealth] (5,0) |- (0,0.5);
```

means to start from `(5,0)` and draw a vertical (denoted by the `|`) and then horizontal (denoted by the `-`) line to the point `(0,0.5)`.

If you wanted the line to go horizontal first and then vertical you would use `-|`.  This is *not* what you want in this case, but might make this syntax easier to comprehend.

### Code: Using Relative Coordinates

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[latex-] (-1,0) -- (9,0) ;
\draw[-latex] (-1,0) -- (9,0) ;
\foreach \x in  {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\x$};
\draw[*-o] (2.98,0) -- (5.02,0);
\draw[very thick    ] (2.98,0) -- (5.02,0);

\draw [red,  thick, -stealth] (5,0) -- ++(0,0.5) -- ++(-5,0);
\draw [blue, thick, -stealth] (3,0) -- ++(0,0.4) -- ++( 4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Code: Using `|-`

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[latex-] (-1,0) -- (9,0) ;
\draw[-latex] (-1,0) -- (9,0) ;
\foreach \x in  {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\x$};
\draw[*-o] (2.98,0) -- (5.02,0);
\draw[very thick    ] (2.98,0) -- (5.02,0);

\draw [red,  thick, -stealth] (5,0) |- (0,0.5);
\draw [blue, thick, -stealth] (3,0) |- (7,0.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Any tips on shading the solution area?

Comment: You could also use the `|-`syntax: `\draw [red,  thick, -stealth] (5,0) |- ++(-5,0.5);`

Comment: @TomBombadil: This seems more of a beginner question, but for completeness I will add that as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can first shade the solution area then draw axis and arrows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[green!20](5,0)rectangle(3,1);
\draw[latex-latex] (-1,0) -- (9,0) ;
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\x$};
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt](a)at(5,0){};
\node[circle,draw,fill=white,inner sep=1.5pt](b)at(3,0){};
\draw[-latex,red](a)--++(0,1.5)--++(-6,0);
\draw[-latex,blue](b)--++(0,1)--++(6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution using the `intersections` library and `intersection segments`. It requires a bit of setup using the proper paths, but the result can be very dynamic and automatic.

I have also redone some of your lines with shorter commands. The `-{Latex}` is supplied by the library `arrows.meta`. While you can still use the old tips, the library `arrows` is supported, albeit deprecated.

### Output

[image: example image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, patterns, intersections, backgrounds}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\tikzset{
    ntp/.style={circle, thin, minimum size=2mm, inner sep=0, fill=white, #1}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[{Latex}-{Latex}] (-1,0) -- (9,0);

\foreach \x in  {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\x$};

\draw[name path=a, -{Latex}] (2.98,0) |-++ (5,.8);
\draw[name path=b, -{Latex}] (5.02,0) |-++ (-5,1);

\draw[very thick, name path=ax] (2.98,0) node[ntp={fill=black}] {} -- (5.02,0) node[ntp={draw}] {};

\path[name path=srt, intersection segments={of=b and a}];

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill [green!30, intersection segments={of=srt and a,sequence={R1}}]
        [intersection segments={of=srt and ax, sequence={--R2}}];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest another way,without arrows, replaced with overlapping coloured areas and playing with transparency. I use `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[x11names, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-1.95,-1.5)(8.95,3)
\psset{dotsize=4pt, arrowinset=0,opacity=0.5, tickstyle=bottomr}
    \pnodes{A}(5,0)(5,0.5)(-2,0)
    \pnodes{B}(3,0)(3,0.5)(8.95,0.5)
    \psframe*[linecolor =RoyalBlue3!60](A1)(A2)
    \psframe*[linecolor=Coral3!40](B0)(B2)
    \psaxes[linewidth=1.2pt, yAxis = false, labelFontSize=\scriptsize]{<->}(0,0)(-2,0)(8.95,0)}
    \psset{linecolor=RoyalBlue3!45!Coral3!45}
    \psdot(B0)\psline(B0)(B1)
    \psset{linecolor=RoyalBlue3!25!Coral3!25, linestyle=dashed, dash=2pt 1.5pt, opacity=1}
    \psdot[dotstyle=o](A0)\ncline[nodesepA=2pt]{A0}{A1}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]