# Multiple Number Lines Not Aligned in Tikz for Algebra Math Worksheet

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode

I am a special education teacher who mainly teaches math and I'm trying to scaffold a lesson on adding polynomials.  I was actually really proud of myself because I built a python script that automates this tex file below (usually it compiles ten problems, but in this MWE, it is just one).  The whole point of the lesson is for students to combine the like terms and then show it on the number line.  I want to have a few problems done for them, but as you can see, the number lines are not coming out aligned.  I created the number lines by tweaking the code found on this [inequality number line post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283868/plotting-inequalities-on-a-number-line).

I am not very experienced with Tikz, but I have spent a lot of time commenting out the above linked post to figure out what the different numbers do to the number line in order to try and use it for my purposes.

> I'm trying to create a number line for each "like term" (think back to high school algebra), but as you can see, something is not right, but I just can't figure it out because I know that when it was just the x^2 terms, it was working just fine.

Here is the MWE code for one problem with the three number lines.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}


    % Problem 0
    % Problem 0
    % Problem 0
    % Problem 0
    % Problem 0
\item Simplify: $(-5x^2+ \; 9x- \; 12) + (8x^2+ \; 8x+ \; 11)$ 
\vspace{0.5cm}

\textit{For your $x^2$ term:}
\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.5]
    \draw[-latex] (-8,0) -- (20,0) ; 
\draw[latex-] (-8,0) -- (20,0) ; 

\foreach \x in  {-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, } 
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);

\foreach \x in  {-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, } 
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\x$};
 \draw[*-] (-5,0.09) -- ++ (0,0);

\draw [red,  thick, -stealth] (-5,0) -- ++(0,0.5) -- ++(8,0);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\vspace{0.5cm} 

\textit{For your $x$ term:}
\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.5]
\draw[-latex] (6,0) -- (34,0) ; 
\draw[latex-] (6,0) -- (34,0) ; 

\foreach \x in  {8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, } 
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);

\foreach \x in  {8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, } 
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\x$};
 \draw[*-] (9,0.09) -- ++ (0,0);

\draw [red,  thick, -stealth] (9,0) -- ++(0,0.5) -- ++(8,0);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\textit{For your constants:}
\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.5]
    \draw[-latex] (6,0) -- (34,0) ; 
\draw[latex-] (6,0) -- (34,0) ; 

\foreach \x in  {8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, } 
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);

\foreach \x in  {8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, } 
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\x$};
 \draw[*-] (-12,0.09) -- ++ (0,0);

\draw [red,  thick, -stealth] (-12,0) -- ++(0,0.5) -- ++(11,0);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: Picture of PDF output of Latex File]

Comment: You provide a lot of description which mostly is irrelevant to your problem. Please, tel us shortly, what is wrong your lines. Should they  start at left border of text? Can you provide sketch of expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To very first approximation you can write a macro that converts the starting coefficient and the shift into a `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% This defines a macro that takes three arguments, one optional one and two
% mandatory ones. The mandatory arguments are the first and second coefficients,
% or, in other words, a coefficient and the shift
\newcommand{\NumberLine}[3][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,#1]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mymin}{min(#2,#2+#3)}% minimum of first coefficient and sum of coefficients
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mymax}{max(#2,#2+#3)}% maximum of first coefficient and sum of coefficients
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{ifthenelse(\mymax-\mymin>0.5,1,0)} %
% check if the values are sufficiently large apart from each other
% at this point tiny difference (<=0.5) are are not supported
\ifnum\itest=1
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xstart}{int(\mymin/2)*2-2} % first tick
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xnext}{\xstart+2} % next tick
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xend}{int(\mymax/2)*2+2} % last tick
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\myscale}{12/(\xend-\xstart)} % zoom factor
 \draw[thick,<->] % draw the horizontal line with arrows
  (\myscale*\xstart-1,0) -- (\myscale*\xend+1,0);
 % draw the blob 
 \path (\myscale*#2,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt] (start){};
 % draw the ticks
 \draw foreach \X in {\xstart,\xnext,...,\xend}
  {(\myscale*\X,3pt) -- ++ (0,-6pt) node[below] {$\X$}};
 % draw the red arrow 
 \draw[red,thick,->] (start) |- ({\myscale*(#3+#2)},1em);
\else
% code for tiny differences could go here
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}


    % Problem 0
    % Problem 0
    % Problem 0
    % Problem 0
    % Problem 0
\item Simplify: $(-5x^2+ \; 9x- \; 12) + (8x^2+ \; 8x+ \; 11)$ 
\bigskip

\textit{For your $x^2$ term:}
\bigskip

\NumberLine{-5}{8}
\bigskip

\textit{For your $x$ term:}
\bigskip

\NumberLine{9}{8}
\bigskip

\textit{For your constants:}
\bigskip

\NumberLine{-12}{11}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, it zooms into the relevant region. You can make it much more versatile but to do that I'd need to know the actual use case.

**EDIT**: Added explanations.

Comment: thanks. I'll take a closer look at it, but this seems to answer my question.

Comment: I am using your code with no problems and I even think after staring at it for about an hour, I think I understand some of the workings behind the code (had to google some stuff and look in the tikz manual for some clarifications).  I like this model because I am able to start with the full number line and red arrow, then get rid of red arrow by deleting one line, and then I can delete the point as well and have student use just the number, but they have to create the directions themselves.  I commented out your code to try and show my own understanding.

Comment: Would this post be an appropriate place for me to post the code with my comments so that people can look at my comments and correct any glaring misunderstandings that I took from the code? Thanks, I'm new to the forum and don't want to break general formatting rules for the stack exchange.

Comment: @DannyKam-Gordon I will be happy to add explanations. But to do this I need to know which parts you are struggling with.

Comment: @DannyKam-Gordon I added some explanations.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I understand how \xstart and \xend work and I also think I understand \xend.  I used pencil and paper to try and solve some of the formulas you made and the scale factor also seems to make sense.  How does the program decide how much space is on either side beyond what we need for the red line?  Also why is the term \stealth used?  When I search, it seems to be about the type of arrow tip used in tikz.

Comment: @DannyKam-Gordon The scale (or zoom) factor is computed via `\pgfmathsetmacro{\myscale}{12/(\xend-\xstart)}`. It is an ad hoc choice (to make the graph fit into the page without becoming tiny), so is the arrow head `stealth`. Both of them appeared to be reasonable choices to me, but the good thing about such codes is that you can adjust them easily if you want to change a detail.

Comment: Thanks, again.  I feel my students did really well that day I used this assignment because I was able to provide the extra scaffolding with the number lines.  I want to learn more about tikz so that I can automate my creation of linear and systems of equations / inequalities.  I've already found a few templates here that I'm playing with.  This is a really great community.

Comment: @DannyKam-Gordon Glad to hear! (I am using Ti*k*Z, too, for my lecture notes.)